# Why does my websites design not load properly when omit the 'www.' from the URL?

Tags: javascript, css, wordpress, caching, elementor

Up until recently (since installing some caching plugins) my website worked fine whether I went to:

```
https://[my website].co.uk
```

or

```
https://www.[my website].co.uk
```

it always just redirected to:

```
https://[my website].co.uk
```

I installed:

**WPRocket** - Browser caching, optimizing CSS, JS deferred

**Autoptimize** - Aggregete JS files

**Asset Cleanup** - CSS files Minification / inline css files

and I setup Cloudflare CDN

Everything was working fine up until I cleared the Cache from cloudflare, on WPRocket I cleared the cache and Clicked 'regenerate critical path CSS' and 'preload cache', I also cleared the cache from autoptimize.

Also I would like to add that I use Elementor and the page design is all distorted whenever the non-www URL is loaded.

I have since removed all the plugins and removed CloudFlare,
I have redirected all internal links in Elementor from https:// to https://www. but the issue still persists, as on Google search the website link comes up as https://[my website].co.uk so it always takes you to the distorted page design.

It seems to work okay when I go to:

https://www.

http://

http://www.

but not on:

https://

If some one could help me understand what is causing this and how I can resolve this it would be much appreciated, I have researched there is a way to re-direct it from https://  to https://www., but I still would like to know whats causing this and if I can get it back to how it used to redirect before.

Thanks for reading.

Comment: Hi, perhaps check to see if any CSS files are missing in the distorted view?

Comment: My question is why are you loading css files from a `cache` folder, or some plugin is doing that... and this is screwing up the correct URL.. example: https://www.[my website].co.uk/wp-content/cache/busting/1/wp-content/cache/busting/1/sccss-1598045687.css

Comment: Try not to use so many caching engines/services/plugins.. Use 1, but configure it well. Test what brakes your website, and what does not..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct location is

https://www.[my website].co.uk/wp-content/cache/busting/1/wp-content/cache/busting/1/sccss-1599078865.css

while it's being searched for at

https://www.[my website].co.uk/wp-content/cache/busting/1/wp-content/cache/busting/1/sccss-1598045687.css

The files have different ends.

The other file is looked for unsuccessfully at

https://www.[my website].co.uk/wp-content/uploads/elementor/css/global.css

but a correct load does not load that file. It loads

https://www.[my website].co.uk/wp-content/uploads/elementor/css/post-2.css

instead.

It appears that the different domains are maintained separately. You might want to look for differences and to synchronize your versions.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, It seems this has happened since using some plugins but removing the plugins hasnt reverted the changes. Not sure how to resolve the issue of different domains being maintained seperately and how to synchronize the versions in wordpress? any advice on where to start?

Comment: @Swifter I would redirect any request as it is from <root1>/some/url?some-parameter=somevalue to <mainroot>/some/url?some-parameter=somevalue. So you would have a single copy which would be used by all items. However, achieving this takes time, you need an adequate solution for the short-term as well. If you version this with a version controller, such as git, then pulling and pushing should help. If all fails, then you might try copying the "good" version to replace anything of the "bad" version. (Don't forget to backup). I hope they all use the same database.